Brother wants to live in an house we inherited equally
My older brother and I are co-trustees and recently inherited our parent's house 50/50. Neither of us is ready to sell and I currently live far away. He has expressed interest in living in our parent's house with his wife and two adult children. Currently, they live a few miles away in a house his wife inherited from her parents. Their current house is much smaller than our parent's home and he feels they would be more comfortable living here. Initially, I was vehemently opposed to the idea, but I'm willing to agree on one condition. Is it possible to make a contract stating if anything happens to him, his family has to move out (back to the house his wife inherited (they wouldn't be homeless)) therefore we would sell the house within a reasonable time and split the proceeds between myself and his two adult children?
To be clear, my issue is I don't mind my brother living here, but if anything happens to him I don't want his wife living here for the rest of her life knowing she has her own free house a few miles away. Is it possible to put in writing that they can only live here while he is residing in the home and sold if he no longer lives there for any reason?

Wouldn't the wife inherit your brother's half then and be a co-owner with you?

@littleadv technically: the wife and the children, but a testament can change that. depending on jurisdiction, there are even things like an "Erbvertrag" (inheritance contract) that would trump even a subsequent will and last testament.

By registering / executing a legal partition deed/agreement you can either deny permission or allow occupation by a brother and family charging rent or even allow them to live in your part of the property free of rent.

Two people (you and your brother) each own a 50% stake in a house. If it is a single-family dwelling, it would be quite weird to live there with both of your families. What does this leave?

Sell the house, split the money.

Special case: one of the siblings sells to the other. The problem here is to find 'fair market value' without going on the open market. If you do that, your brother's family might have to sell their other house to pay you, and then they would own your parents' house without any further question. You get money, they get the house.


Co-own the house, rent it out, split the income and costs.

Special case: one of the siblings rents the house. Again the problem is to find 'fair market rent' without going to the open market. If you do that, and if your brother dies, his wife would be a tenant in a house half owned by you and half by her (if your brother's wife is his heir).



Either way, you should talk to a tax accountant or a tax lawyer regarding the benefits and pitfalls of the option you take. On the long run, the co-ownership is going to produce more friction than single-ownership -- what if the house needs new drains, either this year or next year at the latest? Who decides?

You gave me a lot to think about. Thank you for your response.

@MichelleKahn, whatever you do, get it in writing, get a neutral lawyer to look over it, and if you get money for your stake in the house, do not think of it as your house any more.

Your brother does not need your permission to live in his house
Of course, until the executive of the will (or administrator of an intestate estate) has transferred the property from themselves to you two, he isn’t an owner and neither are you. Whether the executor/administrator will allow anyone (including your brother) to live in the house is a matter between them, as the executor/administrator is the legal owner.
However, let’s assume that the estate as settled and you and your brother are the legal owners, almost certainly as tenants-in-common. That means it’s his house, so he can live there if he wants. Or he can sell his share to anyone who wants to buy it. Or give his share to anyone willing to accept it. Should your brother die, then his share will pass in accordance with his will, probably to his wife or children. It’s also your house, so, so can you.
You and your brother can agree to anything you want but unless you each provide consideration, it will simply be a non-legally binding agreement, not a contract. His agreeing to pay rent, or move out after a certain time would be valid consideration, but you allowing him to live there isn’t - because he can do that already. However, if you agreed to pay him $1 for this, that would make a binding contract.
Of course, if he dies, the contract dies with him and the new owner, his wife say, has no contractual obligation to you. If you want something binding, you would have to have a contract not just with your brother, but also with all potential heirs. This is not legally straightforward so you should get legal advice.
